# Is there an equivalent to the ParseJson action for XML data?

Tags: xml, azure-logic-apps

In Logic Apps we have the [ParseJson](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action) action, which gives the individual fields.

But what about an equivalent for parsing XML?

So for example, if I had an XML over HTTP web service, which received the XML body ...

```
<root>
  <person>
    <firstname>Paul</firstname>
    <lastname>Getty</lastname>
  </person>
  <person>
    <firstname>John</firstname>
    <lastname>Denver</lastname>
  </person>
</root>
```

How could I achieve a similar experience to the `ParseJson` action generating tokens for each of the XML elements (and attributes?)

Comment: add some details on what you're trying to do. converting between json and xml is not trivial. most converters are 95% accurate, but there doesnt exist a 1:1 relationship between json and xml. they are different. so you need to tell us what your goal is. i

Answer (score 2):

json(XML(Body('WhateverYouAreParsing'))). My point here is that you can always cast the XML to JSON and work with it as JSON. I guess you could then recast it as XML with XML() if you really need to reply with XML but that would probably require some additional work. Or use a Transform XML with an integration account and a map.

An azure function could be used to do the parsing also.

Comment: Probably not the answer you were looking for but I hope you can solve your issue with this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that directly.

What I am doing is I am parsing it indirectly through XML - just as @AdAstra mentioned.

1. Generate json schema for your XML - You can use any online converter like for example https://codebeautify.org/xmltojson

   For your XML the Json will look like:

```js
{
   "root": {
      "person": 
      [
         {
            "firstname": "Paul",
            "lastname": "Getty"
         },
         {
            "firstname": "John",
            "lastname": "Denver"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

2. Use Parse JSON Control with TriggerBody as a Content and generated schema pasted in 'Use sample payload to generate schema' - (this will generate Json schema for You)

   [Parse Json component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwncY.png)
3. Enter Expression to parse XML to Json (use Content field in Parse Json Component -> Expression -> **json(xml(triggerBody()))**

   [Parse JSON Expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6oG8.png)
4. Now You can use Your structure as dynamic objects in Logic App designer:

   [Available dynamic content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKJtH.png)